# Choosing single lambda and alpha for prediction on independent dataset (Elastic Net)

Tags: regression, elastic-net

I have two separate datasets, one of which I am using for training and testing, and the other I am keeping as an independent dataset. My goal is to ultimately train an optimal regression model with regularization for predicting values in the independent dataset.

Using glmnet and glmnetUtils, I am cross-validating both the lambda and alpha parameters within each of my folds (k = 10).

However, I am trying to find the single best alpha and lambda values to use on my independent dataset, and it is here with I am lost.

My question is: how can I arrive to a single alpha and lambda value to use on my independent dataset?

Comment: The vignette and other documentation explain how to do this through double cross-validation.  It sounds like you're already doing that, but this raises the issue of what are you trying to ask?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Doing a nested cross-validation with my sample, then within each fold, doing cross-validation of alpha and lambda, creates different "best performing" models for each fold. I was curious as to how I can then arrive to the best parameters to use on an external dataset.

Comment: I don't quite follow, because I thought that cross-validation considered average performance over multiple folds rather than examining performance on each fold individually.